# Why does the code only return the last date to OBS "text"?

Tags: python-3.x, google-calendar-api, obs

I am trying to change the code in a phyton script for OBS studio to show the dates of coming events from a google calendar. But the output to OBS Studio only shows the same (last) date on every event. The script log shows it as it should be thou...

After struggling to find a way to convert the dictionary items to print in a way that I wanted to show it, I finally thought I had made it work the way I wanted.

I am new to python and have basically just searched for answers to how to solve what I needed to change in the code.
It took me days to find out about datetime.datetime and how strftime could work together, and that I needed to upgrade Dateutil to a more recent version to not get some of the errors I got.

Anyway, since I am new to coding and most of this script has been written by someone else it is somewhat hard for me to see where this problem lies.
it works as it should in the script log but the date in "stime" becomes the same for every event when I send it to "text" in OBS Studio.

If anyone could help me with a solution to this, I would be very happy.

```
# Time objects using datetime
dt_now = dt.utcnow()
now = dt.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z' # 'Z' indicates UTC time

#Timeformat
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "sv_SE") # swedish
tmfmt = '%d %B,  %H:%M '


# Gets events currently happending by setting bounds to events happening within a second of current datetime
events = service.events().list(calendarId=cal_url, timeMin=now, timeMax=(dt_now+datetime.timedelta(7,1)).isoformat() +'Z',
                               maxResults=max_events, singleEvents=True, orderBy='startTime').execute()

# Logs the events to console



for event in events['items']:

    mystart = (event['start']['dateTime'])
    stime = dt.strftime(dtparse(mystart), format=tmfmt)
    print(stime)
    #print(datetime.datetime.utcnow().date())
    #print (event['start']['dateTime'])
    print(event['summary'])
    #print(dt_now("%d %b, %Y"))


# Updates the text for each event
count = 0
stream_event_happening = False
record_event_happening = False
for event in events['items']:
    if(count >= max_events):
        break
    text = stime + "\n" + event['summary']
    settings = obs.obs_data_create()
    obs.obs_data_set_string(settings, "text", text)
    source = obs.obs_get_source_by_name(source_names[count])
    obs.obs_source_update(source, settings)
    obs.obs_data_release(settings)
    obs.obs_source_release(source)

    settings2 = obs.obs_data_create()
    obs.obs_data_set_string(settings2, "file", "{}/{}.jpg".format(images_path, text))
    source2 = obs.obs_get_source_by_name(image_sources[count])
    obs.obs_source_update(source2, settings2)
    obs.obs_data_release(settings2)
    obs.obs_source_release(source2)

    count += 1
```

text = stime + "\n" + event['summary']

shows only the same date but different events...

Comment: I guess I should have cleaned up the code from all my test code... sorry about all unnecessary #print lines.

also this is not the full code, just the part that I think is needed to find out where the problem lies...  I can add more if needed...

Answer (score 0):

Wow, just a few minutes later I found a solution on my own... I added:

```
mystart = (event['start']['dateTime'])
stime = dt.strftime(dtparse(mystart), format=tmfmt)
```

just before:

```
text = stime + "\n" + event['summary']
```

and now it works as it should :)